# What is the decomposition of $[G/H]$ in terms of irreducible representations?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $$ be a field. Any $G$-set can be linearized to give a $$-representation of $G$. Each $G$-set is decomposed into a coproduct of indecomposable (transitive) $G$-sets $G/H$ for $H ⊆ G$ a subgroup. For $H=1$, the decomposition of the linearization of $G/H = G$ (the regular representation) contains exactly $\dim(V)$ copies of each irreducible representation $V$. What can be said in the more general case where $H$ is any subgroup?

PS: I'm sorry if it's a standard question but I don't really know what to call this representation $[G/H]$.

Comment: @amWhy I don't agree. This seems like a fine question someone learning about character theory and such might wonder about.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson  It's also what a student learning about character theory might copy from a text book. There is absolutely NO context here.

Comment: @amWhy You're being pretty confrontational. It might be best to take a step back for the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply a hard question in general. As an example, let $G=S_n$ and $H = S_{\lambda_1} \times S_{\lambda_2} \times \cdots \times S_{\lambda_k}$ where $\lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_k = n$. The multiplicities of the irreducible decomposition of $\mathbb{C}[G/H]$ are the Kostka numbers. When $H = C_a \wr S_b$ viewed as a subgroup of $S_{ab}$, the multiplicities are a generalization of Thrall's problem, which has been open for 80 years.

There's the character-theoretic calculation

$\langle V, \mathbb{K}[G/H]\rangle_G = \frac{1}{|G|} \sum_{g \in G} \chi_V(g) \chi_{\mathbb{K}[G/H]}(g^{-1}) = \frac{1}{|H|} \sum_{h \in H} \chi_V(h).$

When $H=1$ this gives the regular representation answer you mentioned. When $H=G$, applying the orthogonality relations gives the expected result.

Continuing from the final equation gives an instance of Frobenius reciprocity,

$$\langle V, \mathbb{K}[G/H]\rangle_G = \langle V|_H, 1_H\rangle_H.$$

That is, your question is equivalent to determining the number of copies of the trivial representation in the restrictions of the irreducible representations of $G$ to $H$. Questions along these lines are known as "branching rules".

Comment: I had some more time and added some details.

Comment: Thank you for your knowledgeable answer. Yes, this gives the dimension of the $H$-invariant subspace in $V$.